# beginners python problem with pandas and csv and analyzing it-reupload with code and error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, valueerror

```
unit_data = pd.read_csv("유닛.csv")
item_data = pd.read_csv("아이템.csv")
trait_data = pd.read_csv("시너지.csv")

#중복이 없는 기준열 만들기

unq_unit1_dt = unit_data['1st-unit'].drop_duplicates()
unq_unit2_dt = unit_data['2nd-unit'].drop_duplicates()
unq_unit3_dt = unit_data['3rd-unit'].drop_duplicates()
unq_item_dt = item_data['0'].drop_duplicates()
unq_trait_dt = trait_data['0'].drop_duplicates()

#저장할 리스트
unit1_d= {};s_u1_d = {};u1_L = []
unit2_d = {};s_u2_d = {};u2_L = []
unit3_d = {};s_u3_d = {};u3_L = []
s_u_d = {};u4_L = []

item_d = {};s_i_d = {};key_L = []

trait_d = {};s_t_d = {};trait_L = []

#unit_data분석
for i in  unq_unit1_dt:
    a = unit_data['1st-unit'].count(i)
    unit1_d[str(i)] = a
    a = 0

for j in unq_unit2_dt:
    b = unit_data['2nd-unit'].count(j)
    unit2_d[j] = b
    b = 0

for h in  unq_unit3_dt:
    c = unit_data['3rd-unit'].count(h)
    unit3_d[h] = c
    c = 0

#데이터 정렬 후 값 추출
s_u1_d = sort_dict(unit1_d); u1_df = pd.DataFrame(s_u1_d); u1_df.to_csv("유닛1.csv", index=False,encoding = 'cp949')
s_u2_d = sort_dict(unit2_d); u2_df = pd.DataFrame(s_u2_d); u2_df.to_csv("유닛2.csv", index=False,encoding = 'cp949')
s_u3_d = sort_dict(unit3_d); u3_df = pd.DataFrame(s_u3_d); u3_df.to_csv("유닛3.csv", index=False,encoding = 'cp949')

for i in range(5):
    u1_L.append(list(s_u1_d.keys)[i])
    u2_L.append(list(s_u2_d.keys)[i])
    u3_L.append(list(s_u3_d.keys)[i])

s_u_d = {'1st-sorted':u1_L, '2nd-sorted':u2_L, '3rd-sorted':u3_L}
s_u_df = pd.DataFrame(s_u_d)
s_u_df.to_csv("유닛추천.csv",index=False,encoding = 'cp949')

#item sort
for i in unq_item_dt:
    item_d[i] = item_data.count(i)
s_i_d = sort_dict(item_d)
s_i_df = pd.dataFrame(s_i_d)
s_i_df.to_csv("아이템정렬.csv",index=False,encoding = 'cp949')

#item 결과 추출
for i in range(3):
    key_L.append(list(s_i_d.keys)[i])
p_i_df = pd.DataFrame(key_L)
p_i_df.to_csv("추천아이템코드.csv",index=False,encoding = 'cp949')

#trait sort
for i in range(len(unq_trait_dt)):
    trait_d[unq-trait_dt[i]] = trait_data.count(unq-trait_dt[i])
s_t_d = sort_dict(trait_d)
s_t_df = pd.DataFrame(s_t_d)
s_t_df.to_csv("시너지정렬.csv",index=False,encoding = 'cp949')

#trait 결과 추출
for i in range(3):
    trait_L.append(list(s_t_d.keys)[i])
p_t_df = pd.DataFrame(trait_L)
p_t_df.to_csv("추천시너지.csv",index=False,encoding = 'cp949')


<ipython-input-80-f08a724d44c7> in <module>
 89     return s_u_df, s_i_df, p_i_df, s_t_df, p_t_df
 90 
---> 91 print(analyze_data())
 92 
 93 

<ipython-input-80-f08a724d44c7> in analyze_data()
 63     #item sort
 64     for i in unq_item_dt:
---> 65         item_d[i] = item_data.count(i)
 66     s_i_d = sort_dict(item_d)
 67     s_i_df = pd.dataFrame(s_i_d)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in count(self, axis, level, numeric_only)
   7782         Myla      1
   7783         """

-> 7784         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)

   7785         if level is not None:
   7786             return self._count_level(level, axis=axis, numeric_only=numeric_only)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_axis_number(cls, axis)
405             except KeyError:
406                 pass
--> 407         raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls}")
408 
409     @classmethod

ValueError: No axis named 44 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

This is my code and error

it supposed to get data from 3 csv files and get what is most duplicated in data

I treid to addkey:value to dict 
but this error happens and i believe there is more....

as this is my first time i used python for my own work,
there is alot of mistakes and way I used is very noob
유닛 .csv si 4646X3
아이템.csv and 시너지.csv has onnly one column

Comment: Please share a sample of your csv and what you tried to get that error.

Comment: i tried to upload my code so i tried ctrl+K and paste my code and errors but it just keep saying something is wrong with my way uploading codes....

Comment: i have uploaded my error and code please check again...